# Compressor + engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering

G´Day,

Something got me thinking and I want to know if anyone else things this is possible.

I wonder if you can buy a electric air compressor, Connect it to your car/truck Battery, and connect the output into your engine to make it more powerful? You may also be able to put the lever inside the car so you can control when to give it that extra boost.

Does anyone else think this is possible since your adding extra air into the engine for combustion?

Comment: Have you never heard of superchargers?  Alternatively, where do you think the energy in the battery comes from in the first place?

Comment: Yes, But i meant just a regular Aircompressor that pulls air form the ouside, Compresses it in a auxilary cylinder, and when a lever is pulled, releases the air through a hose. I wouldnt want to put pure oxygen on it for the fear that if the pressure gets low enough, the engine, tank, and anything near it could explode. there will be a switch inside the cab where you can control when the compressor is on and compressing or idle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is quite possible

Electric Superchargers are a thing.

I think you will find that you will have trouble with always-on boost that you fight with the throttle valve, versus the typical crankshaft-powered blower.  You will also find that you need a pretty large electric motor to power such a device.  You will also find it hard to get air through the blower when it is off.

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to have a switch/stick inside the cab to be able to control when it releases the compressed air, when it is on Ect. I would want to be able to control what all the compressor is doing from inside the cab but it just riddled me if I could make my own homemade supercharger from a regular aircompressor by fitting it either in the hood, or inside the trunk.

Comment: a tank of compressed air won't work.  You won't be able to carry enough air for this to matter, and the air is as likely to blow out the air filter (in reverse) as go into the engine.  You need a supply of air that is proportional to engine size, engines are really just large air pumps.  The compressed gas solution for this is nitrous injection, which is basically adding oxygen to the charge.

Comment: Yes, However i was thinking of a pressure regulator, I just want something as an aircompressor to store readied air for ignition, but for me to not have to go in and replace the tank, so I came up with the theory of slapping an air compressor in the mix.

Comment: There may be a pressure regulator to regulate the pressure from the compressor

Comment: the air tank would have to be too large no matter how it were filled.